# JavaScript not working, wondering how to fix

Tags: javascript, jquery

Wondering how I could fix this js to work correctly. I'm hiding a section to show another and also disabling the hours textboxes if the "off?" checkbox is checked. the hide/show/disable portion works, but the timepicker doesn't work. I'm trying to figure out why it's not working before I try to add the datepicker part of the coding...

Anyways, here is my code for the portion I am referring to...

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="includes/css/adm.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.9.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/js/timepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-sliderAccess.js"></script>

<script>
$("#tstart").timepicker({
timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
stepMinute: 15,
minuteGrid: 15,
hourMin: 6,
hourMax: 16
});
</script>

<script>
$("#tend").timepicker({
timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
stepMinute: 15,
minuteGrid: 15,
hourMin: 11,
hourMax: 23
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript"> 
function fields(){ 
    if (document.getElementById('working').checked == 1){ 
    document.getElementById('tstart').disabled='disabled'; 
    document.getElementById('tend').disabled='disabled'; 
    document.getElementById('type').style.display = 'none';
    document.getElementById('type').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    document.getElementById('off').style.display = 'inline'; 
    document.getElementById('off').style.visibility = 'visible';
    }else{ 
    document.getElementById('tstart').disabled=''; 
    document.getElementById('tend').disabled=''; 
    document.getElementById('type').style.display = 'inline';
    document.getElementById('type').style.visibility = 'visible';
    document.getElementById('off').style.display = 'none'; 
    document.getElementById('off').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
}
</script>

<td class="add_hours_left_top">Date:&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="add_hours_right_top">
                    <input type="text" name="date" id="date" size="22" value="">
                    <input type="hidden" name="work" value="0">
                    <input type="checkbox" title="Check if off work!" name="work" id="working" value="1" onclick="fields();" />Off?
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="add_hours_left">Hours:&nbsp;</td>
                <td class="add_hours_right">
                    <input type="text" name="timestart" id="tstart" size="10" value=""> to 
                    <input type="text" name="timeend" id="tend" size="10" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="add_hours_reason_select" colspan="2" id="type">
                    <div class="add_hours_type_name">Type of work to be done:</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="work_type" value="0" checked />
                    Temps <input type="radio" name="work_type" value="1" /><b>&middot;</b>&nbsp;
                    Scrub Floors <input type="radio" name="work_type" value="2"/></br>
                    Leave Early or Later <input type="radio" name="work_type" value="3"/><b>&middot;</b>&nbsp;
                    Training <input type="radio" name="work_type" value="4"/></br>
                    </label>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="add_hours_reason_select" colspan="2" id="off" style="display:none;">
                <div class="add_hours_type_name">Reason off work:</div>
                    <input type="hidden" name="why_off" value="0" checked />
                    Request <input type="radio" name="why_off" value="1" /><b>&middot;</b>&nbsp;
                    Medical Leave <input type="radio" name="why_off" value="2"/></br>
                    </label>
                </td>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you included jquery ? since you are using it

Comment: there are no element by id `type` or `off`? It will throw an error saying `no property style for undefined`

Comment: Are you also including jQueryUI and/or whatever plugin is required for `.timepicker()` method?  Please construct a jsFiddle.

Comment: Side note: `timepicker()` has to be used with in `$(function(){})` ie dom ready

Comment: What @ArunPJohny said.  That's probably the answer.

Comment: 'type' and 'off' have elements and id's and yes I'm using jquery and the plugin, just forgot to post that part...

Comment: Can you also check the console of your browser to see if there are any errors logged

Comment: Side note: Since you are using jQuery you can rewrite your method as `function fields(){
 var checked = $('#working').is(':checked');
 $('#tstart').attr('disabled', checked ? 'disabled' : '');
 $('#tend').attr('disabled', checked ? 'disabled' : '')
 
 if(checked){
  $('type').hide();
  $('off').show();
 }else{
  $('type').show();
  $('off').hide();
 }
}`

Comment: Any error in your console?

Comment: Like was said before by @ArunPJohny, you _must_ enclose your code in a DOM ready function.  Otherwise, `#tstart` and `#tend` don't yet exist when you call `.timepicker()` -> it **will** throw an error and it **will not** work.

Comment: Also who is calling the `fields()` method?

Comment: just saying a couple of imgs are not found

Comment: Construct a jsFiddle.

Comment: @ArunPJohny, he has inline JS on the checkbox element, `onclick="fields();"`.

Comment: I try to make the jsFiddle and the time picker works. vice versa when testing it elsewhere

Comment: how I got it thus far... kind of new to fiddle...
http://jsfiddle.net/Spydie/nHAcA/

Comment: also the rewrite you gave me Arun permanently disables the hour fields and doesn't show/hide the <tr>'s

Comment: It's working in your jsFiddle because the DOM ready wrapper function is applied automatically even if you don't specify it.  Again, for the fourth time, wrap your code in a DOM ready function:  http://jsfiddle.net/nHAcA/2/

Comment: And in jsFiddle, you simply load jQuery and jQueryUI from the "Choose Framework" section of the left panel.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quote OP:

> "...but the timepicker doesn't work. I'm trying to figure out why it's
>   not working..."

Without the DOM ready handler, the code will not work because the HTML elements do not yet exist when the time-picker initialization method is called.  The DOM ready function ensures that the DOM is fully constructed *before* the `.timepicker()` method is fired.

Your time-picker works great when you wrap the code in a [DOM ready function](http://api.jquery.com/ready/).

**DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/nHAcA/2/**

```
$(document).ready(function () {  // <-- use a DOM Ready handler function

    $("#tstart").timepicker({
        timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
        stepMinute: 15,
        minuteGrid: 15,
        hourMin: 6,
        hourMax: 16
    });

    $("#tend").timepicker({
        timeFormat: "hh:mm tt",
        stepMinute: 15,
        minuteGrid: 15,
        hourMin: 11,
        hourMax: 23
    });

    function fields() {
        if (document.getElementById('working').checked == 1) {
            document.getElementById('tstart').disabled = 'disabled';
            document.getElementById('tend').disabled = 'disabled';
            document.getElementById('type').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('type').style.visibility = 'hidden';
            document.getElementById('off').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById('off').style.visibility = 'visible';
        } else {
            document.getElementById('tstart').disabled = '';
            document.getElementById('tend').disabled = '';
            document.getElementById('type').style.display = 'inline';
            document.getElementById('type').style.visibility = 'visible';
            document.getElementById('off').style.display = 'none';
            document.getElementById('off').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        }
    }

});
```

If we remove the DOM ready function and disable the DOM ready in the jsFiddle, the time-picker just stops working:  http://jsfiddle.net/nHAcA/3/

Read more:  http://api.jquery.com/ready/

---

**Bonus points:**

Since you're using jQuery, get rid of your inline `onclick` function and replace it with the [jQuery `on()` method](http://api.jquery.com/on/).  See:  http://jsfiddle.net/nHAcA/4/

```
$('#working').on('click', function () {
    if (document.getElementById('working').checked == 1) {
        document.getElementById('tstart').disabled = 'disabled';
        document.getElementById('tend').disabled = 'disabled';
        document.getElementById('type').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('type').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        document.getElementById('off').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('off').style.visibility = 'visible';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('tstart').disabled = '';
        document.getElementById('tend').disabled = '';
        document.getElementById('type').style.display = 'inline';
        document.getElementById('type').style.visibility = 'visible';
        document.getElementById('off').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('off').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }
});
```

Also, with jQuery...

`document.getElementById('off')` can be replaced with `$('#off')`

And...

```
document.getElementById('off').style.display = 'none';
```

can be replaced with...

```
$('#off').css('display','none');
```

And...

```
document.getElementById('off').style.display = 'none';
document.getElementById('off').style.visibility = 'hidden';
```

can all be replaced with...

```
$('#off').css({
    'display': 'none',
    'visibility': 'hidden'
});
```

or maybe you'll want to try [the jQuery `hide()` method](http://api.jquery.com/hide/) instead.

```
$('#off').hide();
```

It's the same as `display: none`. `visibility: hidden` is superfluous when you're using `display: none`. Since the latter also gives the element zero size and takes it out of the flow, it's pointless to take away its visibility... it's already gone.

Then use [the jQuery `.show()` method](http://api.jquery.com/show/) to bring the element back.

```
$('#off').show();
```

As per the docs: *"This is roughly equivalent to calling `.css('display', 'block')`, **except** that the display property is restored to whatever it was initially. If an element has a display value of `inline`, then is hidden and shown, it will once again be displayed `inline`."*

Also see the [jQuery `.css()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/css/), [jQuery `.prop()` docs](http://api.jquery.com/prop/), and [jQuery Selectors docs](http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/).

You get the idea....

```
$('#working').on('click', function () {
    if ($(this).prop('checked')) {
        $('#tstart').prop('disabled',true);
        $('#tend').prop('disabled',true);
        $('#type').hide();
        $('#off').show();
    } else {
        $('#tstart').prop('disabled',false);
        $('#tend').prop('disabled',false);
        $('#type').show();
        $('#off').hide();
    }
});
```

**Updated Demo:  http://jsfiddle.net/nHAcA/6/**

Comment: thank you Sparky, works like a charm! and thanks to the help on learning on how to do it!